# What does this do when working with backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

`window.router = new RouterModel`(extended from backbone router)

I can't figure out what its purpose is in an program I'm looking at.

Would I do this to change the router anytime I need to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It assigns an object of `RouterModel` to the global variable `router`.

> Would I do this to change the router anytime I need to?

Yes, if you want to change the global `router` variable.

Comment: Is it possible that calling this if you construct a new view when it is initialized would cause every call to grow exponentially?

Comment: @fancy: By calling this you mean `window.router = new ...`? If that's what you mean, no, you are merely going to assign something else to the variable `router`.

Comment: I'm facing an issue I think is related to this where logging out/in triggered over and over results in each call growing exponentially until it's calling tons of logout/login functions every time I logout/login.

Comment: In the router initialization I am building and rendering a new layout views. Do I need to clear other views when I do this or something?

Comment: @fancy: I am not a whiz in backbone.js, and I am not aware what `RouterModel` does, so I can't comment much on that. If you share the `RouterModel` maybe we can help you with the issue you are facing, but  assigning this object to the global variable `router` has nothing to do with what goes on inside `RouterModel`.

Comment: @fancy - that's a separate issue that has been discussed many times on stackoverflow. some searches should find what you need.

Comment: @Derick I can't find any, could you point me to one? Thanks very much.

Comment: for example, i answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379263/disposing-of-view-and-model-objects-in-backbone-js/7383008#7383008 ... the question isn't the same, but the cause and solution are