# How to clear views before rendering another one? Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Multiple view instances are happening in my application when I change layouts. I think it's possibly because they use the same `el` but I'm not sure. How would I go about clearing out views before setting up new ones? Or should I create wrapper `el` element for each one and clear them from the dom instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you're probably running into zombie views caused by left-over bindings to various types of events. the solution i provided here will help you with that: [Disposing of view and model objects in Backbone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379263/disposing-of-view-and-model-objects-in-backbone-js/7383008#7383008)

Comment: This worked. I'd like create this close method in a base view and give it the ability to iterate through its extended views and unbind all of their events. Have you tried anything like this?

Comment: yeah, i've done similar things. you can add a close method to the base backbone view like this: `Backbone.View.prototype.close = function(){ /* your code here */ }`

Comment: Fancy, you can also extend Backbone.View with your own base view and then have all views just extend off that. This is what I do.

Comment: @Mauvis - I do the same when I need a sub-set of my views to share functionality. When I want all of my views to share the functionality, I use the Backbone.View.prototype.