# How to bind/unbind window events in backbone view

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, backbone-views

I need to bind event on window object inside backbone view and when navigated to other backbone view i want to unbind window event. Is there any efficient way to do this in the backbone??

example:

```
class Example.Views.EntriesList extends Backbone.View

  initialize: ->

    $(window).unbind('scroll').on 'scroll', _.bind(@scroll, this)
```

Above code works perfect for this view but when navigated to different backbone view then scroll bind is still present. I wanted to remove all the events binded to window when view changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're really supposed to be calling [`View#remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) to clean up a view before forgetting about it. So you should have a `remove` like this in your view:

```
remove: ->
    $(window).off('scroll')
    super()
```

Keep in mind that you're potentially interfering with other code by unbinding **all** the listeners to the `'scroll'` event on `window` when you `$(window).off('scroll')` and that might do more than you want. You'd be better off using namespaces:

```
initialize: ->
    # The caller should have cleaned everything up so no need to `off` here.
    $(window).on('scroll.EntriesList', _.bind(@scroll, @))
remove: ->
    $(window).off('scroll.EntriesList')
    # or .off('.EntriesList')
```

to keep your view from interfering with other parts of your application.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look, at this answer: [Disposing of view and model objects in Backbone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379263/disposing-of-view-and-model-objects-in-backbone-js)

If this is a common requirement in your application I suggest you to try [Backbone.Marionette](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette), which helps you in this and other ways

```
Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  onClose: function(){
    // custom closing and cleanup goes here
  }
});
```

[Reference](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.itemview.md#close--onclose-event)