# How to delete old backbone views

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, view

I have searched the internet for ways to trigger the destruction of old views.
There are functions to do this, however, I don't know how to trigger them.  Ideally, there would be a way to trigger the destruction on the event of closing a view.
I can't find a way how to trigger that particular event.

Answer (score 2):

You should call `view.remove()` to trigger its destruction as specified in the documentation http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove

For example, if you had:

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        ...
    },

    render: function() {
        ...
    }
});
```

You can later call `myView.remove()` provided you have a reference to `myView` available.

This method should also remove any event listeners tied to the view if you are using the `listenTo` (recommended) method as opposed to the `on` listener. You could also add `view.off()` to ensure that the events are removed.

Additionally, you will need to add a way for views to listen to a close event so you can call the remove and off methods. You should refer to [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569704/destroy-or-remove-a-view-in-backbone-js) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379263/disposing-of-view-and-model-objects-in-backbone-js).

Comment: I want to trigger the destruction when i nagivate to a new view, so the view.remove function must be triggered between leaving the old view and entering the new one. That is my problem, I don't know when or where to use the remove function. I hope this will help you understand the issue.

Comment: You should refer to the links I posted at the bottom of my answer. One way to do this is to modify the Backbone.View class to include a close method. Another is to create a parent class that all your views inherit from which support the close event functionality. Finally, could override the navigate method in your Backbone.Router to perform destruction of an active view, then call the original navigate function or manually setup routes using router.route with a callback function that removes active views.

Comment: i tried to destroy an existing view in the router by creating a global variable that is associated to the existing view, and destroying it before creating a new view that's newly associated with that global variable, but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: Would you be able to post your code and what you have tried in your original question?

Comment: @FrançoisLalonde: You'd usually have a `this.currentView` in your router to hold then current view, then you'd `if(this.currentView) this.currentView.remove(); this.currentView = new WhateverView()` when the router switches to a new view.

Answer (score 0):

This old but fantastic piece [by Derick Bailey](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/) does a great job at explaining the issue and how to solve it. As Monica rightly suggested this relies on `view.remove()` but you can update your router to destroy your existing view - 
Try something similar to

```
if (currentView) { 
  currentView.remove();
  currentView = newView();
}
```

Comment: I tried to use 

if (currentView) { 
  currentView.remove();
  currentView = newView();
}

Comment: I tried to put a this.currentView = null in the initialize of my router, in the cleanup function, the if statement is not entered, it's like if (this.currentView)  doesn't work..

Comment: At some point you will need to update this.currentView to the view that you wish to remove. It probably makes sense to do this within your individual backbone routes and then creating a separate function which contains your if statement which can be called each time you navigate to a new backbone route.